# How to indent a paragraph inside a TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation

How do I get paragraphs inside a node to indent?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,text width=9cm] {
        indent in paragraph long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text.

indent in paragraph long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to put a `minipage` environment within the node, and to set `\parindent` to whatever indent width you want:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,text width=9cm] {
   \begin{minipage}{9cm}
      \parindent=3em
      indent in paragraph long text long text long text...

      indent in paragraph long text long text long text ...
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you leave out the minipage, then your first paragraph will not be indented.  You could force the indent by saying `\indent` before the first line:

```
\node[draw,text width=9cm] {
      \parindent=3em
      \indent indent in paragraph long text long text long text...
};
```

which would also work.  The second way is probably more efficient for TeX (one fewer minipage to compute), but the first may be somewhat more robust.

Comment: Or a more `latex`-y way: `\setlength{\parindent}{3em}`. In the second solution, only the first paragraph needs the `\indent` command.