# Paragraph indentation with tikzposter

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, tikzposter, parindent

I try to create a `tikzposter` containing some longer pieces of text. I would like those to have indented paragraphs. I tried setting `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}`, but that didn't solve the problem (it absolutely changed nothing).

So my question is: How do I enable `\parindent` in `tikzposter`?

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for debugging purposes

\title{\bfseries Test title}
\institute{My institute}
\author{My colleagues and me}

\usetheme{Board} %board, envelope, wave, autumn
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BlueGrayOrange,colorOne=gray!70,colorTwo=darkgray!80,colorThree=gray!10]{Spain}%Russia
\usebackgroundstyle{Rays}
\usetitlestyle{Default}
\useblockstyle{Board}
\useinnerblockstyle{Default} % Table

\settitle{\centering\vbox{\centering
    \color{titlefgcolor}\vspace*{1em}\scalebox{1.3}{\bfseries\huge\scshape\@title}\par\vspace*{1em}
    {\LARGE\@author\par}\vspace*{1em}{\large\@institute}
}}
\changefontsizes{32pt}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}
    \maketitle[width=.7\textwidth] % See Section 4.1
    \block{Block with wrong paragraph indentation}{
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \innerblock{Test}{
                \lipsum[2]\par
                \lipsum[1]
            }
            \innerblock{Test}{
                \lipsum[2]\par
                \lipsum[1]
            }
        \end{multicols}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a real answer, but if you set the `\parindent` *inside* the `innerblock` (i.e. right before `\lipsum`) you get indentation.

Comment: I think `tiksposter` block are `nodes`, so probably you need: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22656/how-to-indent-a-paragraph-inside-a-tikz-node

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks. That was the hint I needed. So you could post that as an answer.

Comment: (I see my comment was not very clear, as I gave exactly the same hint ...)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't understood your solution. I've deleted my answer. Please, write yours.

Comment: @Ignasi It's the same as yours, so just undelete. I just said you don't need the `\indent`, probably because (referring to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22656/how-to-indent-a-paragraph-inside-a-tikz-node) the text is first put in a `\parbox`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Done it. Please fill free to edit and correct the answer if you consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TikZPoster` defines `blocks` with `TikZ-nodes` and their contents is a `\parbox` which is not indented by default. But you can force indentation in each particular block adding `\setlength{\parindent}{3em}` before the text. (See [How to indent a paragraph inside a TikZ node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22656/how-to-indent-a-paragraph-inside-a-tikz-node?rq=1), and comments from Torbjørn T. to this answer and question)

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for debugging purposes

\title{\bfseries Test title}
\institute{My institute}
\author{My colleagues and me}

\usetheme{Board} %board, envelope, wave, autumn
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BlueGrayOrange,colorOne=gray!70,colorTwo=darkgray!80,colorThree=gray!10]{Spain}%Russia
\usebackgroundstyle{Rays}
\usetitlestyle{Default}
\useblockstyle{Board}
\useinnerblockstyle{Default} % Table

\settitle{\centering\vbox{\centering
    \color{titlefgcolor}\vspace*{1em}\scalebox{1.3}{\bfseries\huge\scshape\@title}\par\vspace*{1em}
    {\LARGE\@author\par}\vspace*{1em}{\large\@institute}
}}
\changefontsizes{32pt}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}
    \maketitle[width=.7\textwidth] % See Section 4.1
    \block{Block with wrong paragraph indentation}{
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \innerblock{Test}{
                \setlength{\parindent}{3em} %<--- Indentation
                \lipsum[2]\par
                \lipsum[1]
            }
            \innerblock{Test}{
                \lipsum[2]\par
                \lipsum[1]
            }
        \end{multicols}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `\indent`. Edit: The block text is put in a `\parbox`, in an `\hbox`, and that box is measured, and later put in a `\node`, see `tikzposter.cls`.